# Log out from site

Tags: javascript, php, html

I use my project php oop. this class get log in detail from data base and create session to user.

```
<?php

 include("../Controller/DBConnection/DBConnectionController.php");
 session_start();

  class LoginModel {

public function getLogin() {
    $name = "";
    $type = "";

    if (isset($_POST["submit"]) && $_POST["submit"] == "submit") {

        $username = $_POST["username"];
        $password = $_POST["password"];

        $query = "SELECT username, password,'guser' AS type FROM g_user WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password' UNION
                    SELECT username, password,'suser' AS type FROM s_user WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password' UNION
                    SELECT username, password,'admin' AS type FROM admin WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";

        $result = mysql_query($query); 

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $name = $row["0"];
            $type = $row["type"];
        }

        if (mysql_affected_rows() == 0) {
           return ("invalidlogin");
          // $_SESSION["Error"]=$username;   
        } else {
            $_SESSION["username"] = $name;
           // $_SESSION['userid']   = "";
            if ($type == "admin") {
                $_SESSION["adminname"] = $name;
                return ("adminlogin");

            }else if($type == "guser"){
                return ("guserlogin");

            }else if($type == "suser"){
                return ("suserlogin");

            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

I want to log out my web page when click log out link.but when i click it , load login page again , but i click browser back button or view another opening tab i again load previous   user page. how can i sole this , when i log in to site i create below session.

This is my view class part of code .witch show log out link.

```
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="SUserHome.php">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="send D.php">Disease Details</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../../forum/forum_index.php" target="_blank">Forum</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../../Controller/logout.php" >Log Out</a></li>
                    </ul>
```

This is logout.php

```
<?php

  if (session_id())
      session_destroy();

      header("location:../View/LoginView.php");
```

but did not work.
please , I hope some solution.Help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be checking if a session variable exists to grant access to users. To log out from your site, simply destroy the session, this will prevent access effectively 'logging' the user out:

```
session_start()
session_destroy(); //destroy sessions but session data will still be avail on same page so redirect is needed after this
header('location:index.php'); // redirect to login or index page or logout success page
exit;
```

OR

```
session_start();
unset($_SESSION); //will destroy session superglobal on current and subsequent pages
echo $_SESSION['adminuser']; //will echo nothing at this point 
header('location:index.php'); // redirect to login or index page or logout success page if you want
exit;
```

Comment: I must create new logout.php ..?

Comment: It is up to you. You can create a logout success page or simply destroy the session and redirect to the index page.

Comment: i create new logout.php and put this code but still when i click back button browser load previous  user detail.

Comment: Don't forget `session_start();` see edited.

Comment: @Anchove thank you for your answer. but still when i logout and click browser back button again load previous page. but it may be some time programmatically error ....! i think page is load without session........!

Comment: Clear you cookies and cache for your new changes to take effect. It shouldn't preserve any session data when clicking the back button.

Answer (score 1):

Your `session_unset()` is executing immediately. Putting it near the URL in the link is not making it execute when you click the link.

Answer (score 0):

Create a simple logout.php with:

```
<?php

if(session_id())
    session_destroy();
```

Comment: can i put this in my 'LoginView.php' page.if it can ,where i put it on html page.? regards

Answer (score 0):

make a new file logut.php and put this code into it

```
session_destroy();
unset($_SESSION['adminname']);
header('location:login.php');
```

Comment: `unset` is not necessary. `session_destroy` will 'unset' the session variable, having both is redundant.

Comment: Please edit your answer to add an explanation of how your code works and how it solves the OP's problem. Many SO posters are newbies and will not understand the code you have posted.